# I cannot accept an input for this program and it directly shows the response based on the current time

Tags: python

I am a Python beginner and am working on this practice question to show Good morning sir,etc and in this case i cannot accept any input from the user, it just shows the result based on the current time.

PROGRAM CODE:

```
import time
timest = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print("The current time is:", timest)

ch = int(input("Would you like to check current time or enter hour to check? \n 1.Check current time \n     2.Enter hour to check"))

if ch == 1:
    timeh = int(time.strftime('%H'))
    timem = int(time.strftime('%M'))
    times = int(time.strftime('%S'))
if ch ==2:
    timeh = int(input("Enter hour:"))
    timem = int(input("Enter minute:"))
    times = int(input("Enter second:"))

if 6<timeh<12 and 1<timem<59 and 1<times<59:
    print("Good morning sir")
elif 12<timeh<4 and 1<timem<59 and 1<times<59:
    print("Good afternoon sir")
elif 4<timeh<8 and 1<timem<59 and 1<times<59:
    print("Good evening sir")
else:
    print("Good night sir")
```

I am expecting it to ask for choice if the user selects 1 he gets the response based on current time and if he selects 2, he get response based on the time entered by user

Comment: Which of these Python versions you tagged are you actually using?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: [The input works fine](https://replit.com/@codeguru/HauntingRelevantBundledsoftware). When I enter "2", I get prompts to enter the hour, minute, and second. However, I think there is problems with the logic.

Comment: For example, what happens if the time is 12:00:00? And what should it do instead?

Comment: note that `12<timeh<4` will never be True, so one of the elif blocks will never be executed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### The 1 versus 2 choice is working correctly

You can modify the code as shown below to prove it.

```
import time
timest = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print("The current time is:", timest)

ch = int(input("Would you like to check current time or enter hour to check? \n 1.Check current time \n     2.Enter hour to check"))

if ch == 1:
    timeh = int(time.strftime('%H'))
    timem = int(time.strftime('%M'))
    times = int(time.strftime('%S'))
    print("Option 1")
if ch ==2:
    timeh = int(input("Enter hour:"))
    timem = int(input("Enter minute:"))
    times = int(input("Enter second:"))
    print("Option 2")

if 6<timeh<12 and 1<timem<59 and 1<times<59:
    print("Good morning sir")
elif 12<timeh<4 and 1<timem<59 and 1<times<59:
    print("Good afternoon sir")
elif 4<timeh<8 and 1<timem<59 and 1<times<59:
    print("Good evening sir")
else:
    print("Good night sir")
```

#### However the  choice of messages will not work

- Problem 1. You have not dealt with zeros. In fact, you can ignore the minutes and seconds, can't you?
- Problem 2. You have not dealt with the boundary hours, such as the hour around 6 o'clock. Change one of the "<"s on each line to a "<=".

#### Correct code for choice of messages:

```
if 6<=timeh<12:
    print("Good morning sir")
elif 12<=timeh<16:
    print("Good afternoon sir")
elif 16<=timeh<20:
    print("Good evening sir")
else:
    print("Good night sir")
```

Comment: but why wont the choices of the messages work??

Comment: pls provide me with the correct code and what changes I should do??

Comment: Correct message code shown at end

Comment: It does not work either

Comment: Make sure you use the version with 24 hour clock (16, 20 hours) - please report back what problem you see, rather than just "it does not work"

Comment: Nevermind, I found my mistake. I forgot to save the code.

Comment: Hahahahahaaha! Happens to us all some times! 8-)